# Where is this CSS style information coming from?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to fix a CSS stylesheet to make sure that a styled element is shown on the web page.

This is how the CSS stylesheet is linked:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/default/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="" charset="utf-8"/>
```

This is the HTML code:

```
<a href="search" class="floatleft shadowed">Advanced Search</a>
<a href="post_ad" class="floatright post-ad">Post an Ad Now</a>
```

Now when I use the "Inspect Element" tool in Google Chrome and click on the first line, I see this:

[image: working CSS]

The `Advanced Search` link shows up on the page. No problems there. But if I click on the next line, I see this:

[image: not working CSS]

Because of this, the `Post an Ad Now` link doesn't show on the page. I don't know where this CSS is coming from and it is certainly not specified in `style.css` and Google Chrome doesn't show the source (e.g. style.css:101)

```
.pop-up-ad, .popadtext, .popunder-adv, .popup-ad, .popupAd, .popupAdOuter,
.popupAdWrapper, .popup_ad, .portalCenterContentAdBottom, .portalCenterContentAdMiddle,
.portalCenterContentAdTop, .portal_searchresultssponsoredlist, .portalcontentad, .post-ad,
.post-adsense-bottom, .post-advert, .post-advertisement, .post-googlead, .post-load-ad,
.post-nativeadcarousel {
    display: none;
}
```

How can I make sure that the `Post an Ad Now` link shows on the page?
And how do I figure out where the mystery CSS information is coming from?

Comment: It may be browser style. Use `!important` to take effects.

Comment: You should either use another CSS class name, or add this CSS in your stylesheet: `.post-ad{ display: block !important; }`

Comment: Adding the `!important` attribute worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since most of the classes mention adverts in some way or another, it almost certainly comes from an adbocking browser extension you have installed.

Comment: comes from AdBlock exactly

Comment: Yes, I have AdBlock installed. Will using `!important` fix that? Or will I have to change the class name to something else?